# When can i get this error: [L] is not a hexadecimal digit ?

Tags: java, apache, http, servlets

I am doing a `httpRequest.getParameterMap()` in my servlet which is giving me the below error:

```
[L] is not a hexadecimal digit
    at org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil.convertHexDigit(RequestUtil.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil.parseParameters(RequestUtil.java:400)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil.parseParameters(RequestUtil.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.mergeParameters(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:894)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.parseParameters(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getParameterMap(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:389)
```

The request object contains various objects in the parameter list which is seen by running app in debug mode. Most objects are String objects. One of the parameter is a hashed value which is encoded before being added to the request. The hashed parameter can be something like `ubXG%252b0Yd99%252fN0HXxSwzxCw%253d%253d`.
Can this parameter cause the above error in `getParamterMap()` method.

Comment: Do a regex search for `%(L|.L)` - probably some percent meant as percent. However % is hex-encoded as %25, So maybe twice decoded?

Comment: `convertHexDigit` is called if `case '%'`, check @JoopEggen hint